# Get current latitude and longitude in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to get latitude and longitude from current location dynamically. Is there any plugin or custom code to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Web [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) as follows:

```
const vueComp = new Vue({

    data () {
        return {
            /* Reactive properties */
        };
    },

    created() {

        const success = (position) => {
            const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
            const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            // Do something with the position
        };

        const error = (err) => {
            console.log(error)
        };

        // This will open permission popup
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

});
```

Also, if you need a promisified plugin, you can use [`vue-browser-geolocation` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-browser-geolocation).